# Page Break Acumatica Report

Tags: erp, acumatica

I am using SubReport in Accumatica after certain records. Is there any ways to let Report move rest of records to Next Page While printing or in PDF Export.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PageBreak property in the report designer - you can set it on any group or detail section to generate a page break before and/or after the printing of a specific section. It's also possible to have sections that are conditionally visible, so with some imagination you can have very fine control on when a page break is done.